# Calculate Area and Circumference of a Circle with input in C++

Tags: c++

I am writing a code for class and I thought I hat it all down pat. However, can not get any feedback from the input when I compile this on XCode.

My code is as follows:

```
/*
 James George Hayek
 PCCC Assignment 2
 Prof Siegel

 This program will calculate the area and circumference of a circle.
 */

#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
using namespace std;

int main () 
{

    float radius;
    float circumference;
    float area;

    cout << "Please enter the radius of a circle: ";
    cin >> radius;
    cout << "\n";

    circumference = 2 * 3.1416 * radius;
    area = 3.1416 * radius * radius;

    cout << "************************************" << "\n"
         << "*Area and Circumference of A Circle*" << "\n"
         << "************************************" << "\n"
         << "\tRadius= " << radius << "\n"
         << "\tArea= " << area << "\n"
         << "\tCircumference= " << circumference << "\n";

    cin.get();


    return 0;

} //end main
```

Okay, I just trouble shot this and it seems as though this works in the terminal but I can not get it to respond in the console in XCode. Should I not worry about this?

Comment: It looks good to me, and works under GCC/Linux - I think it's probably an issue with your Xcode setup, about which I know zilch.

Comment: Yay for using `"\n"` instead of the stupidly inefficient and pointless `::std::endl`.  Now, you can include then in the string, you don't have to print them out as a separate string.  :-)

Comment: are you aware of 'double' type in C++? Also 3.1416 is of type double in C++03 at least

Comment: In addition to the answers below, note that you should perform error handling when you extract input from cin.  With your current code, if the extraction fails (for example, if the user enters "hello" when asked for the radius), the radius will be left uninitialized.  You need to test the state of the stream after performing the extraction to make sure it succeeded (using `cin >> radius; if (cin) { /* worked */ } else { /* failed */ }` or more succinctly, `if (cin >> radius) etc.`).

Comment: Hmm, we spoke about this in class the other day. We have not gotten that far just yet but I do understand that the program can tank if a wrong input is entered. Thank you, I will look into testing a stream after a cin statement.

Answer (score 1):

You got your tab back wards on your output: `/t` should be `\t`. I don't see anything else wrong with the code. (tested)

```
cout << "************************************" << "\n"
      << "*Area and Circumference of A Circle*" << "\n"
      << "************************************" << "\n"
      << "\tRadius=" << radius << "\n"
      << "\tArea=" << area << "\n"
      << "\tCircumference=" << circumference << "\n";
```

Answer (score 0):

Your program compiles and runs fine but its not pretty printing the result because you need `\t` to get a tab printed and you've used `/t`.

`\t` is a single tab char where as `/t` is two separate char `/` and a `t`

Here is the list of [escape sequences](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h21280bw%28VS.80%29.aspx) available.

Comment: Ah ha, I noticed this justtt after I posted the code. Thanks, I made the change.

Answer (score 0):

It's '\t' not '/t'.

it should be:

```
 << "\tRadius=" << radius << "\n"
 << "\tArea=" << area << "\n"
 << "\tCircumference=" << circumference << "\n";
```

Answer (score 0):

Other posts have pointed out the reason/fix.

Just noticed:

Your code silently loses precision in the statements as there is a implicit double to float standard conversion that applies behind your back:

```
circumference = 2 * 3.1416 * radius;  (since 3.1416 is of type double, 
                                       the type of rhs is double).
area = 3.1416 * radius * radius;      (same here)
```

So, you lose precison. Don't do it unless it is intentional. Compile with the strictest warning level though that is not guaranteed to bring out all lurking issues.

> $5/10 - "Otherwise, if either operand
>   is double, the other shall be
>   converted to double."

Comment: Hmm, I thought float would be enough, I will look into using double precision for this and other codes that require it.

Comment: Yeah, good to know about but when you're hardcoding 3.1416 I don't think you need the extra digits ;-).

Answer (score 0):

Area of Circle = (Radius * Radius) * PI

function area_of_circle($radius){

$area = pow($radius, 2) * pi();

return $area;
}

// given value $radius = 2;

$area = area_of_circle($radius);

echo "Radius of Circle : ".$radius."
"; echo "Area of Circle : ".$area;

[download here](http://sourcecodeexchange.blogspot.com/2014/06/php-calculate-area-of-circle.html)

Answer (score 0):

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<conio.h>
void main()
{

float radius,area;
clrscr();  // Clear Screen

printf("nEnter the radius of Circle : ");
scanf("%d",&radius);

area = 3.14 * radius * radius;

printf("nArea of Circle : %f",area);
getch();

}
```

[i already translated the code from PHP to C++](http://sourcecodeexchange.blogspot.com/2014/06/php-calculate-area-of-circle.html)